# Aligning two maps with different projections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, overlay, alignment

I am trying to add historic borders to a modern blank world map. The files I have are all bitmap format and the historic borders are in separate regional maps (Africa, India, North America, Western Europe, etc.). I am quite new to this and am struggling considerably with accomplishing this. I was hoping to overlay the historic border maps as a transparent layer which would perfectly match the coastlines and rivers of the base map. I have attached two maps as a demonstration of what I mean (not in bitmap format as they were too large to do so). [image][image]

Comment: You may try to get vector data for the modern border ( look at natural earth data for exemple) as vector would be easier to superpose on raster of historical border

Answer (score 2):

If you can establish the projection of the historical maps (or make an intelligent guess), then you could register these against a modern coverage like the Natural Earth ones using the coastline, islands and lakes. Then you could digitize the historical borders into a new layer. There might be faster and more accurate ways but this would suffice for broad-scale display.

If I was doing it, I would use Global Mapper because it is good at warping the image to fit known points. There may be similar capacity in QGIS but I haven't used it. However, there is a useful tutorial here: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem I'm having is even after converting the map data from Natural Earth to the right projection (Robinson) via MapShaper, they still don't align properly. It is very close but not as close as I would prefer.

Comment: I did take a look at Global Mapper but unfortunately that would be way out of my budget. For some reason QGIS closed mid-use while I was using it and now I can't find it anywhere on the computer. I still have the install manager but it won't work so I may have to download it again from the website and hope it works (took six hours last time!).